# Page Flashing On Scroll

Tags: background-image

Any ideas why this page: http://mpdteam.net/projects.html is flashing when it scrolls? I've determined it's due to the background of the main content container, but why? is it a eye-trick, an image flaw, a browser flaw, or a code flaw? The code is easily viewable with view source or dev tools.

Let me know if you need anymore info. thanks.
(also, feel free to re-tag. i'm having a mind-blank for good tags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because it uses finely spaced grey and white lines.

It is perhaps an example of the [Moiré pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern), although this is more typically reserved for two overlapping grids at different angles.

I always assumed on a PC this occurred because of the redraw time between the two colours, and how finely spaced the lines are. The lines not perfectly aligning with pixels (e.g. anti-aliasing) would further enhance the flickering effect.

To fix it, try changing the size of the bands (e.g. try zooming out or in on the current page, and moving the browser, and note how you get reduced and even none of the described flickering effect).

Alternatively, you may want to apply a blur such that the difference between bands was softened (not sure if this would necessarily help).

Another suggestion that research yields is that it is due to background redrawing/scaling. However, a fixed background (as compared to a repeating one) isn't particularly applicable to your page.

In any case, for an in-depth discussion of some of the concepts involved, check out this awesome page (http://www.techmind.org/lcd/)

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the indepth answer. i'll definitely check this out. thanks.